# Vite-Laravel-React App hosting on Apache Sever

Tags: reactjs, laravel, apache, vite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEhdl.png)`I created a project on Vite Laravel React method and its working fine. but when I host after build the page becomes blank . It seems some build/asset/file.css and build/asset/file.js not load at the time of laravel start entry page public/index.php

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.